# Angular:How to print full URL in console

Tags: angular, angular-services

I work on angular 4, how to print full url like `http://somthing/getHeros?hero=hero`  in console. My service method is

```
getHeros(hero: string): Observable<Hero[]>{
const url = "http/somthing/getHeros",
const params = new HttpParams.set("hero", hero);
console.log(this.httpClient.get<Hero[]>(url, {params: params}));
return this.httpClient.get<Hero[]>(url, {params: params})
```

My above console doesnot print the URL it prints the response. Please help me print full URL.

Comment: because you are getting response .`httpClient.get<Hero[]>(url, {params: params}))`

Comment: but I want to see the URL, which is getting formmed

Comment: what is hero:Hero object or string or id?

Comment: it a string, corrected my question

Comment: You can use a **HttpInterceptor** to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to read the URL for debugging purposes, you can use the "Network" panel of your browser's development tools.

If you want to access the URL in your code, you can write an HTTP interceptor (see, e.g., [http-interceptor](https://theinfogrid.com/tech/developers/angular/building-http-interceptor-angular-5/)). The interceptor receives an `HttpRequest` object with `url`, `params` and `urlWithParams` properties, among others.

Comment: yes, network panel is what i was looking for. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have said it  hero is string you can create url like `const url = "http/somthing/getHeros/"+hero;` directly.
And then pass it to **get()** method it will return you response.

```
getHeros(hero: string): Observable<Hero[]>{
    const url = "http/somthing/getHeros?"+hero;
    console.log(url);
    return this.httpClient.get<Hero[]>(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the Chrome inspector. Click on Network tab. Click on XHR. If you made a XHR request, that'll show up on the network tab with the entire request headers, bodies etc.